# Preview problems in AUCTeX when using certain document classes

Tags: document-classes, auctex, preview

I just changed document class to lipics (class files [here](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/styles/lipics/lipics-authors.tgz)) which is used for various conference proceedings, i.e.

`\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{lipics}`

I now have problems rendering previews in AUCTeX. Sections and display formulas are not rendered. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

As you can see, inline formulas are rendered correctly. I have no idea how to tweak AUCTeX to cope with the lipics document class. Rendering the whole pdf with pdflatex is no problem, so the source file is certainly fine.

Comment: Seems a pure Emacs and AuCTeX issue. Please take into consideration to ask the AuCTeX mailing list, https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/auctex

Comment: If I ask to do the preview for the sample document, even adding an `equation` environment and an inline formula, I get the expected result.

Comment: Interesting. When I try the sample document I still have the problem with the preview. I preview with C-c C-p C-d.

Answer (score 3):

After consulting the AUCTeX mailing list, I received very helpful answers (see [this link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2013-09/msg00033.html)). In short, the solution was to tell AUCTeX to render previews with pdflatex instead of latex. In short, enter PDF mode with

> C-c C-t C-p

and that's it. In my particular case, I can now correctly preview documents in the document class I had problems with.

Comment: This is not a solution but just a work-around. In fact i.e. you cannot preview eps graphics in this way. Am I wrong?

Comment: I suppose it is like rendering a document with either `latex' or 'pdflatex'. The former works for eps graphics and the latter for pdf graphics.